# An Unblech that may/will boil off

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, cooking-bishul

If someone uses a water blech ([Unblech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blech#Unblech) or k'deirah) to exploit whatever halachic [advantage](http://jewishcooking.blogspot.com/2006/03/blech.html) he sees from this pot on a pot method, does he have to anticipate the possibility that the water inside will boil off and not use the blech if the boiling off is a possibility (or probability)?

Does his use of the blech have to keep in mind what could happen to change the status of the blech back to a "regular" blech? Or does halacha allow him to use it by judging what it is now without concern for what could happen?